# DAX measure to create daily targets from different monthly values

Tags: excel, powerbi, dax, powerpivot

I have a fact table as shown below:

[image]

I wanted to get the daily tons of it which is simply dividing it by number of days per month. I have created a manual per day table, but I found it cumbersome. Do you have any idea how to efficiently do it?

Comment: Your number of day per month is count by how many transaction per month or simply the days for the month?

Comment: I am using a uniform 31 days per month.

Answer (score 1):

Quite a simple approach can solve your problem, hope it is your expected output:

First add new Dax measure:

```
Measure = SUM(Sheet1[Ton])/31
```

And use matrix table as following:
[image]

The original data:

[image]

Comment: Yeah. This is exactly what i wanted. On top of this I wanted to link to my calendar table and to show the cumulative per month. So it will cumulate for march and it will reset and give me the cumulative value for april

Comment: Why do you need to link calendar, i don't really get your point. Anyway accept the answer if helping :)

Answer (score 0):

Crate a new Table with SUMMARIZE function

```
Tabel = SUMMARIZE(Yourtable, Yourtable[Month], "Tons_Month", SUM(Yourtable[Tons]))
```

Then add a custom column Tons_Daily in Power Query and use formula

```
 Tons_Daily = [Tons_Month]/31
```

Comment: Yeah. This is exactly what i wanted. On top of this I wanted to link to my calendar table and to show the cumulative per month. 

So it will cumulate for march and it will reset and give me the cumulative value for april .